# Why is redis pipeline giving cross slot error when I am only sending one key per evalsha?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I am using redis-py, and I am trying to pipeline multiple evalsha commands. Each evalsha command works on a single key.

Despite that, at the end of pipeline.execute(), I am getting a Crossslot error.

A crosslot error should be thrown when I am using multiple keys in a single evalsha command, if they hash to different slots, but I am only using a single key at a time, then why am I getting this error?

Here's a version of that code -

```
def batcher(self, iterable, n):
args = [iter(iterable)] * n
return itertools.zip_longest(*args)

redis_node = redis.Redis(host=host, port=port, db=0)    

for batch_ids in self.batcher(redis_node.scan_iter('V*'), self.SCAN_SIZE):
    redis_node_pipeline = redis_node.pipeline()
    for id in batch_ids:
        redis_node_pipeline.evalsha(sha, 1, id)

    responses = redis_node_pipeline.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, I discovered the client library redis-py, while creating the pipeline, takes an argument transaction=True

It tries to execute all the commands in the pipeline as a transaction. If it is trying to execute it as a transaction, it will try to check if the keys involved in all the commands hash to the same slot, and hence it was giving the crosslot error.

If you want to use redis pipeline without transaction, you should do

```
redis_node_pipeline = redis_node.pipeline(transaction=False)
```